# How to add a score system in java for an android game

Tags: java, android, timer

I have a game where it has a Start/Stop button. The aim of the game is to see if you can count to 10 in your head. When you press the start button the (invisible)timer starts and when you press stop it should stop the timer and display your score on the page. The closer you get to 10 seconds the better score you get.
I want to know how I can implement a scoring system for this because it is based on time I don't know how to convert it to an int? Below is the code that makes it run.

```
 private Runnable updateTimerThread = new Runnable() {

    public void run() {

        timeInMilliseconds = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - startTime;

        updatedTime = timeSwapBuff + timeInMilliseconds;

        int secs = (int) (updatedTime / 1000);
        int mins = secs / 60;
        secs = secs % 60;
        int milliseconds = (int) (updatedTime % 1000);
        timerValue.setText("" + mins + ":"
                + String.format("%02d", secs) + ":"
                + String.format("%03d", milliseconds));
        customHandler.postDelayed(this, 0);
    }

};
```

Answer (score 0):

You could implement a scoring system where users get a maximum of 10,000 points for clicking at exactly 10 seconds and a smaller score as the time difference gets bigger.

```
long clickTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime; //time between start and stop clicks
long timeDifference = Math.abs(10000L - clickTime); //absolute time difference between 10 second and the users clicks

int score = 10000; //set maximum score
score = score - (int) clickTime; //subtract the time difference from the score to get actual score
```

You should remember to use `System.currentTimeMillis()` to find your startTime. This method will give a negative score if a user takes more than 20 seconds to click, so you could add another statement to reset it to 0 if you prefer.